# Дата в БД MySQL из DateTimePicker'a

Tags: mysql, delphi, дата

в DateTimePicker1 из mySQL дата форматируется и переворачивается автоматически запросом:

```
...DATE_FORMAT(`from_date`, "%d.%m.%Y") as `from_date`,...
```

Но вот позже из DateTimePicker1 ни как не могу её перевернуть в формат mySQL, т.е. превратить из **27.02.2001** в **2001-02-27**, она туда автоматически не переворачивается и получается **2027-02-20**. Пытаюсь делать кодом:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.add('UPDATE table_name SET `from_date`=DATE_FORMAT("'+DateToStr(DateTimePicker1.Date)+'",''%Y-%m-%d'') WHERE `number` = 1');
```

Пробовал перед SQL-запросом делать `DateTimePicker1.Format:='yyyy-M-d';` не помогло.
Странная ситуация с форматом времени у разных платформ - неужели эта планета не может определиться с единым стандартом времени? Время ведь на планете одного исчисления. В общем отошёл от темы вопроса.
Как быть? Как записать в БД дату из DatePicker'а

Comment: Почему вы используете строки, а не типизированные параметры? Часть вопрос с преобразованием точно ушло бы.

Comment: `неужели эта планета не может определиться с единым стандартом времени?` только когда мы станем единым целым...

Comment: @AlexR. Наверное потому что mySQL изучал самостоятельно. Многого до сих пор не знаю.
Вы имеете ввиду по типу: `ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('family').Value:= Edit1.text;`?
И хочу решить не часть вопроса, а закрыть его полностью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как быть? Как записать в БД дату из DatePicker'а

**Вариант 1:**

Явно указать формат, заменив `DateToStr(DateTimePicker1.Date)` на `FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', DateTimePicker1.Date)`

**Вариант 2:**

Явно указать формат, заменив `DateToStr(DateTimePicker1.Date)` на перегруженный вариант `DateToStr(DateTimePicker1.Date, MySQLFormatSettings)`

При этом заранее нужно объявить переменную `MySQLFormatSettings: TFormatSettings` и установить у нее формат даты, и, желательно, десятичный разделитель.

**Вариант 3:**

Использовать параметрический запрос

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.add('UPDATE table_name SET `from_date`=:Date1 WHERE `number` = 1');
ADOQuery1.ParamByName('Date1').AsDate := DateTimePicker1.Date;
```

**PS**

> Странная ситуация с форматом времени у разных платформ

Для внутреннего представления в программах всё чаще применяют ISO 8601: `YYYY-MM-DD` Он наиболее универсален.

> неужели эта планета не может определиться с единым стандартом времени?

Нет, не может. Люди слишком привязаны к своей истории и культуре.

> Время ведь на планете одного исчисления.

Вы несколько не осведомлены

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Первый вариант привлёк своей простотой в использовании.

Answer (score 0):

Надо избегать преобразование строк в даты и обратно.

У `DateTimePicker1` есть свойство `DateTimе`, которое указывает на введенное значение.

В запросах везде где только можно необходимо указывать параметры. Это снимет проблемы с преобразованием и проверкой типов. Также это позволяет БД лучше оптимизировать запросы.

```
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('family').Value := DateTimePicker1.DateTimе;
```

У параметра должен быть тип `ftDateTime`, а сам запрос изменится на

```
UPDATE table_name 
   SET `from_date`= :p_date
WHERE `number` = :p_num
```